# Gigya removeLoginEmails removes last login id

Tags: sdk, gigya

Is there a way to stop `accounts.setAccountInfo` from deleting an email if it is the last standing login ID?

Currently if I have 2 verified emails both loginIds and issue 2 requests removing one email at a time (I know I can pass a comma separated list) I end up with an account that can't login anymore as no login Id is left.
Both return 200 ok and no error code.

I've looked for an etag implementation so I can at least force some sort of an optimistic lock but couldn't find support for it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, as in the case a user's email(s) were compromised, there needs to be a way to disable login of the account until the user can have their information updated via a customer service representative. There is no out-of-the-box way for an end-user to use this particular parameter, so, unless a currently logged in user is manually calling the method from the JS console, there is no way for this scenario to accidentally happen.

From the server-side, if you are worried about a specific application from calling this method and require restricting a specific app from accessing this particular API you can assign the application key to a permissions group with restricted permissions. ref:https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Console+Administration#ConsoleAdministration-PermissionGroups

If you think this behavior should change, please open a ticket from your Gigya/CDC account dashboard for investigation.

Comment: Figured as much.
Is thre a way for me to use an optimistic lock on a read so I can make sure from the server side this won't happen? Something similar to an etag implementation?